# How to add my open files with my Qt app in Pythons subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, c++, qt, subprocess, popen

I have made a simple notepad editor using Qt that I try to open with:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["myNotepadApp.exe", "myFile.py"])
```

this opens my app but not with the specified file myFile.py open. Is there any changes I need to make to my Qt code for my Qt open function? Does opening files with this subprocess.Popen() function even call my Qt open function?

```
void objectDetector::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open file");
    QFile file(fileName);
    currentFile = fileName;
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly| QFile::Text)){
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Warning", "Cannot open file : " + file.errorString());
        return;
    }
    setWindowTitle("Object Editor");
    QTextStream in(&file);
    QString text = in.readAll();
    ui->textEdit->setText(text);
    file.close();

}
```

Here is the constructor of the UI object if it is releveant

```
objectDetector::objectDetector(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::objectDetector)
{
    setWindowTitle("Object Editor");
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setCentralWidget(ui->textEdit);
}
```

Here is the current main.cpp:

```
#include "objectdetector.h"

#include <QApplication>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    auto* od = new objectDetector(&a);
     is left in here is for us.
    const auto args = a.arguments();
    if (args.size() > 1)
    {
        
        const auto fileName = args[1];
        // Pass the first arg to objectDetector as file name to open it
        od->openFile(fileName);
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your app from the command line with the file name as argument? The answer to that will tell you where your problem is.

Comment: @mahkitah it does the same thing as stated in the question - opens the app but the file doesn't open. Does my constructor need to take in arguments or something? Have edited my initial question to include my ui object constructor.

Comment: You may want to add `c++` to the tags. Now you will get mostly pyqt people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your call to `Popen` does is about the same as if you type the following into your shell:

```
myNotepadApp.exe myFile.py
```

So, "myFile.py" is passed as an *argument* to your executable but it fails to do anything with it. The functionality is missing from your Qt application and the whole issue is unrelated to Python's `Popen`.

In C++ (like in C), you can access these arguments in `main()` using `argc`, or the count of arguments and `argv`, the vector of arguments themselves. Qt also processes arguments for some [Qt-specific flags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qapplication.html#QApplication) and offers [`QCoreApplication::arguments()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#arguments) as a convenient way to access them.

As you did not share your `main.cpp`, I'll have to guess what it looks like. In order to make it work, you'll need to do something like the following:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Pass argc and argv to QApplication
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    // Create your classes
    objectDetector od;
    // Get arguments back from QApplication
    // Qt will have stripped argv of all Qt-specific flags so whatever is left in here is for us.
    const auto args = app.arguments();
    if (args.size() > 1)
    {
        // args[0] is the name of your executable, we don't want that
        const auto fileName = args[1];
        // Pass the first arg to objectDetector as file name to open it
        od.openFile(fileName);
    }
    od.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

And you will have to give your class `objectDetector` a method to handle a file name. Luckily you already wrote all the code we need:

```cpp
void objectDetector::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open file");
    openFile(fileName);
}

// This needs to be public
void objectDetector::openFile(const QString& fileName)
{
    // Looks familiar? It's your own code extracted as a method
    QFile file(fileName);
    currentFile = fileName;
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly| QFile::Text)){
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Warning", "Cannot open file : " + file.errorString());
        return;
    }
    setWindowTitle("Object Editor");
    QTextStream in(&file);
    QString text = in.readAll();
    ui->textEdit->setText(text);
    file.close();
}
```

This way, the first argument will be treated as a file name and your application will attempt to open it.

There's room for improvement, however. It will not handle multiple file names and passing a string that does not name a file will result in a "Cannot open file" message box. For anything more complex than getting the first argument, consider setting up [QCommandLineParser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcommandlineparser.html).

Qt features an [example text editor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-mainwindows-application-example.html). This seems to do largely what you are trying to accomplish. It's using a `QCommandLineParser`. You may be able to get inspiration from there.

Comment: Thanks! What should the constructor look like for the `new objectDetector(&app);` call to work - my current constructor as show above doesn't match this call. I have tried a few but I am not super familiar with the Qt types.

Comment: @Lookdatway my mistake. You can leave out the `&app` parameter. I was trying to hand a `QObject* parent` so Qt's memory management can clean up when the app terminates. It will work without the parameter but you may get an error when you close your app. If you edit your question and share your `main` I will try to fit it in.

Comment: Updated my question to include my main. It didn't really have anything in before your answer - the main now is literally just what you included in your answer.

Comment: Thank you. In the mean time I edited my answer. The whole dynamic memory allocation (using `new`) was a bad idea. I threw it out. I also included a link to a Qt tutorial which looks very much like your app. The tutorial offers step-by-step guidance which is very hard to give in an answer on SO.

Comment: The GUI also is not appearing when I run the app - build runs fine however.

Comment: Because the call to `show()` was missing.

Comment: Please don't mindlessly copy code. Go back to your original `main` and try to work the part with `app.arguments()` in. I had no way of knowing how your `main` function looks. I made the mistake of taking the `main` of one of my apps as template for my answer. Mine is a more complex app and it doesn't feature a GUI. This is exactly how I botched my answer.